# Program terminates without giving error

Tags: java

Every time I run my program, it terminates part of the way through without leaving any error messages. This occurs at the same place each time, somewhere between lines 57-82. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

```
public class DutyDecider_console {
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a, b, c, d, e, f, go, candidateone, candidatetwo, candidatethree, candidatefour, candidatefive, candidatesix;
    double z = Math.random();
    go =("go");

    String optionch;
    System.out.println("Welcome to Duty Decider.");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Please type in your duty you wish to be decided.");
    optionch = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You want to decide who will be " +optionch +".");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Please type in the possible candidates for doing the " +optionch +".(Type one name at a time and press enter after each name. ");
    System.out.println("There can be a total of six candidates. Type 'go' after the desired number of candidates have been entered.");
    a = input.nextLine();
    candidateone = a;

    if(candidateone.contains("go")){
        System.out.println(candidateone +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
    }
    else if(!candidateone.contains("go")){
        System.out.println(candidateone +" has been confirmed.");
        System.out.println(" ");
        b =input.nextLine();
        candidatetwo = b;
        if(candidatetwo.contains("go")){
            System.out.println(candidateone +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
        }
        else if(!candidatetwo.contains("go")){
            System.out.println(candidatetwo +" has been confirmed." );
            System.out.println(" ");
            c = input.nextLine();
            candidatethree = c;
            if(candidatethree.contains("go")){
                if(z<0.5){
                    System.out.println(candidateone +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                }
                else if(z<1.0&&z>0.5){
                    System.out.println(candidatetwo +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                }
            }
            else if(!candidatethree.contains("go")){
                System.out.println(candidatethree +" has been confirmed.");
                System.out.println(" ");
                //where I believe the problem begins
                d = input.nextLine();
                candidatefour = d;
                if(candidatefour.contains("go")){
                    //z by thirds, point .33
                    if(z<0.33){
                        System.out.println(candidateone +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                    }
                    else if(z<0.66&&z>0.33){
                        System.out.println(candidatetwo +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                    }
                    else if(z<1.00&&z>0.66){
                        System.out.println(candidatethree +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");

                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(candidatefour +" has been confirmed.");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        e = input.nextLine();
                        candidatefive = e;
                        //where I believe the problem ends.
                        if(candidatefive.contains("go")){
                            //z by fours, .25
                            if(z<0.25){
                                System.out.println(candidateone +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                            }
                            else if(z<0.50&&z>0.25){
                                System.out.println(candidatetwo +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                            }
                            else if(z<0.75&&z>0.50){
                                System.out.println(candidatethree +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                            }
                            else if(z>0.75&&z<1.00){
                                System.out.println(candidatefour +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day!");
                            }
                        }
                        else if(!candidatefive.contains("go")){
                            System.out.println(candidatefive +" has been confirmed.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            f = input.nextLine();
                            candidatesix = f;
                            if(candidatesix.contains("go")){
                                //z divisible by 5, point twos
                                if(z<0.20){
                                    System.out.println(candidateone +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                    System.out.println(" ");
                                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                                }
                                else if(z<0.40&&z>0.20){
                                    System.out.println(candidatetwo +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                    System.out.println(" ");
                                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                                }
                                else if(z<0.60&&z>0.40){
                                    System.out.println(candidatethree +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                    System.out.println(" ");
                                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                                }
                                else if(z<0.80&&z>0.60){
                                    System.out.println(candidatefour +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                    System.out.println(" ");
                                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day!");
                                }
                                else if(z<1.00&&z>0.80){
                                    System.out.println(candidatefive +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                    System.out.println(" ");
                                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day!");
                                }
                            }
                            else if (!candidatesix.contains("go")){
                                System.out.println(candidatesix +"has been confirmed.");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                //z divisible by 6, point .1666
                                if(z<0.1666){
                                    System.out.println(candidateone +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                    System.out.println(" ");
                                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                                }
                                else if(z<0.3332&&z>0.1666){
                                    System.out.println(candidatetwo +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                    System.out.println(" ");
                                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                                }
                                else if(z<0.4998&&z>0.3332){
                                    System.out.println(candidatethree +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                    System.out.println(" ");
                                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                                }
                                else if(z<0.6664&&z>0.4998){
                                    System.out.println(candidatefour +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                    System.out.println(" ");
                                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day!");
                                }
                                else if(z<833&&z>0.6664){
                                    System.out.println(candidatefive +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                    System.out.println(" ");
                                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day!");
                                }
                                else if(z<1.00&&z>0.833){
                                    System.out.println(candidatesix +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                                    System.out.println(" ");
                                    System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day!");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }   
}



}
```

This program is supposed to choose from up to six candidates who will do a certain duty or chore of the user's choice.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: How come `go=("go");`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If your program terminates, it must be throwing some exception.

Comment: @assylias Yes I have and have gotten no errors.

Comment: This looks like a great opportunity to acquaint yourself with a Java debugger.  This would allow you to step through the executing program, line by line, and examine the runtime behavior and values.  You can use this to determine any logical errors or any code that's behaving in an unexpected way, as well as get detailed information about any exceptions being thrown.

Comment: @shekharsuman go is the string name and "go" there so that the user could type go in the console. I don't think i can explain it very well but it appears to not work at all without it.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your code and pinpoint where the program is exiting, then view the values around that area to see what's up

Comment: @DapperDrew This code is rather, hmm, unusual. You should learn about arrays, loops, and floating point (double) before you try to write programs like this one.

Comment: @laune yeahh, I just started learning how to code about three weeks ago. I've used loops and arrays before but haven't really mastered them. For some reason writing it like that seemed more simple in my head than it turned out.

Comment: I think it should be said that you might run into edge case number problems. See `else if(z<0.6664&&z>0.4998){...} else if(z<833&&z>0.6664){...` won't catch anything if `z==0.6664`. You need to change some `<` into `<=`. Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/266187) an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this if statement:

```
if(candidatefour.contains("go")){
                //z by thirds, point .33
           if(z < 0.33){

           }
           else if(z < 0.66 && z > 0.33){

           }
           else if(z < 1.00 && z > 0.66){

           }
           else{
               // lots of code
           }

  // close all open blocks, method, class.
```

You associated the last else with the wrong if.

Comment: Ah thank you! I had a feeling it was something like this but couldn't figure out what it was. Forgive me, I just started learning how to code about three weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing bracket:

```
//where I believe the problem begins
                d = input.nextLine();
                candidatefour = d;
                if(candidatefour.contains("go")){
                    //z by thirds, point .33
                    if(z<0.33){
                        System.out.println(candidateone +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                    }
                    else if(z<0.66&&z>0.33){
                        System.out.println(candidatetwo +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");
                    }
                    else if(z<1.00&&z>0.66){
                        System.out.println(candidatethree +" has been selected to " +optionch +".");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("Thank you for using 'Duty Decider. Have a nice day");

                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(candidatefour +" has been confirmed.");
```

The last two lines should read something like:

```
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(candidatefour +" has been confirmed.");
```

As laune pointed out, the bracket is not actually missing but misplaced, so you also have to remove one of the many closing brackets at the end of your program.

Comment: It's not "missing" (otherwise it would not compile) but it is in the wrong place. You'll have to remove a closing bracket elsewhere!

Comment: You are right, it is misplaced. Just remove one of the many closing brackets at the end of your program after you added it before the "else" and you should be fine.

Comment: Edited my answer and added @laune 's point

Comment: Thanks! Forgive me for such a silly issue. I have only started learning to code about three weeks ago.

Comment: As a first measure, you could try to split up your code into separate methods. That will help you keep an overview of the structure.